# Libreoffice Calc XY scatter graph - How do I add minor gridlines?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

The option is greyed out under Format > Grid. I have looked [here](https://help.libreoffice.org/Chart/Grids) and [here](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/7070/can-i-add-custom-grid-lines/) but when I change Format>Axis>Y axis>Scale and set it off automatic and change the minor interval count, minor gridlines still do not show up.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out - need to go to insert>grids and then select X & Y.